# What's $R[x]/(x^2)$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can someone explain what the quotient ring $R[x]/(x^2)$ is isomorphic to? I know it's weird because it's reducible/has double root, but I'm not exactly sure what the implications of that, or how to proceed.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but what is R? Any ring? Or the field of real numbers? As for the question: R[x]/(x^2) is isomorphic to R[x]/(x^2). Since this answer will certainly not be enough, please specify your question.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Intuitively, you are "killing" polynomials of degree $2$ or higher in the quotient ring. So only degree $0$ or degree $1$ polynomials will "survive", and they would have the following multiplication rule:

$(a+bx)(c+dx)=ac+(ad+bc)x$.

Can you make this formal?

Answer (score 9):

Usually, it's the other way around: you find an isomorphism $A \to \mathbb{R}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ because you understand $\mathbb{R}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ and want to understand $A$.

To better understand $\mathbb{R}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$, it may be of use to note that if $f$ is a polynomial, then

$$ f(a + \epsilon) = f(a) + f'(a) \epsilon $$

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately, we cannot write $f'(a) = \frac{f(a+\epsilon)-f(a)}{\epsilon}$ since $\epsilon$ is a zero divisor.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it's what you're after, but it's often called the [ring of dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) over $\mathbb{R}$.

It's the coordinate ring of the variety* consisting of a single double point at the origin on the real number line.

*As Martin points out below, "variety" typically refers to a reduced scheme (with additional properties). By definition, a single fat point is not reduced since it's local ring has nilpotents. So I should really say "...of the non-reduced scheme consisting of..."

Comment: A little caution: Often varieties are assumed to be reduced. I would speak of a scheme here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Good point.