# Prove that $R x R$ is not isomorphic to $R[x]/(x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I prove that the following rings are not isomorphic to each other? I have already proved that $R \times R$ is not isomorphic to $C$. I also need to show that $C$ is not isomorphic to $R[x]/(x^2)$. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Thorgott yes I do

Comment: @DietrichBurde I’m sorry I don’t understand what you mean

Comment: I am sorry, let me try again. We have that $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2-a)$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ by the duplicate. Now take $a=0$. This answers your question. Of course $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2)$ has zero divisors, so cannot be a field, so cannot be isomorphic to $\Bbb C$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks for replying so fast but I’m not sure how the duplicate shows that because the answer uses that $R = \bb{Q}$

Comment: Ah, I see. I should have added [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894653/whats-rx-x2-isomorphic-to).